# В чем разница между методами html() и append() ?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Может кто-нибудь объяснить мне в чем разница этих 2 методов при добавлении нового блока?
Какой лучше использовать по скорости?
Благодарен.

Comment: Если Вам действительно важна скорость, используйте чистый js.

Comment: отличный совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неужели так тяжело заглянуть в саму либу jquery

appendChild будет медлинее если его использовать в цикле, так как операции с дом - это медленно

```
append: function() {// тот же appendChild
        return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
                var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
                target.appendChild( elem );
            }
        });
    },
```

Если использовать, после цикла и передавать ему строку с хтмл то он будет быстрее

```
html: function( value ) { // тот же innerHTML, но с блекджеком
        return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
            var elem = this[0] || {},
                i = 0,
                l = this.length;

            if ( value === undefined ) {
                return elem.nodeType === 1 ?
                    elem.innerHTML.replace( rinlinejQuery, "" ) :
                    undefined;
            }

            // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
            if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) &&
                ( jQuery.support.htmlSerialize || !rnoshimcache.test( value )  ) &&
                ( jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value ) ) &&
                !wrapMap[ ( rtagName.exec( value ) || ["", ""] )[1].toLowerCase() ] ) {

                value = value.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" );

                try {
                    for (; i < l; i++ ) {
                        // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                        elem = this[i] || {};
                        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
                            elem.innerHTML = value;
                        }
                    }

                    elem = 0;

                // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
                } catch(e) {}
            }

            if ( elem ) {
                this.empty().append( value );
            }
        }, null, value, arguments.length );
    },
```

сравнение скорости привел [[@binliz](/users/8664/binliz)](/users/8664/binliz) , только вот так делать не нужно

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + '<div>Test ' + i + '</div>';// работа с ДОМ в цикле - это плохо
}
```

Comment: Кибер, 

    appendChild будет медлинее если его использовать в цикле, так как   операции с дом - это медленно

jQuery - это библиотека яваскрипт. Естественно, будет быстрее работать код на яваскрипте, а вы говорите, что медленее...

Comment: ЛЮБАЯ операция с ДОМ в цикле медленнее чем аналогичная операция вне цикла и без разницы это добавления через appendChild или $(), разница в том что обе операции будут быстрее вне цикла.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/24

Comment: так а посмотреть код jquery.js?

append используеть javascript appendChild а html использует append

Answer (score 0):

`html()` заменяет содержимое селектора, а `append()` добавляет новое содержимое в конец селектора.

[Update](https://www.google.ru/search?q=jquery+html+and+append+method+speed&oq=jquery+html+and+append+method+spped&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.14109j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=jquery+html+and+append+method+speed) для тех, у кого сломался гугл и кто не может элементарно измерить время выполнения двух циклов.

Update 2, для тех, кто не может посмотреть, что у [`append()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L325) и [`html()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L407) "под капотом".

Comment: > в чем разница этих 2 методов **при добавлении нового блока**? Какой лучше использовать по скорости?

Comment: подобного ответа я и ожидал....Читаем более внимательно

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, сравнить время не проблема. Интереснее услышать от знающих людей, что там под капотом.